# Check for domain extension with PHP or JS

Tags: php, javascript, tld

First of all I am a php beginner so please be as specific as possible.
Basically I want a php/javascript that does the following:

if the domain has a  .de extension then add the text "this is a german site"
else add the text "this is not a german site"

it's also ok if you do it with the lang="de-DE" instead of the domain extension.

Comment: it depends. From where you get the domain extension? if the string only contains a domain name, `parse_url()` so better, otherwise `preg_match()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the domain extension use php's [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
$extension = pathinfo($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if($extension == "de")
{
echo "this is a german site";
}
```

Also see: [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me. I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, try something like this:

```
<?php
//~ $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$domain = "domain.de";

if (preg_match('/(.*?)\.de$/', $domain)) {
    echo "is german";
} else {
    echo "is not german";
};
?>
```

Greatings.

Comment: I get no error at all. I don't get any messages either. I am using joomla.

Answer (score 0):

```
var isDE="";
var extension=location.hostname.split(".");
extension=extension[extension.length-1];
if (extension=="de") isDE="this is a german site".
//do whatever you need with isDE, e.g. document.write(isDE);
```