# Rewrite command from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Below is the code i have developed till now:

```
$extension = pathinfo($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if($extension == "de")
{
echo "this is a german site";
}
```

The above function is simple and works well in php, though i need it in javascript, how should i rewrite it?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253136/how-to-get-domain-name-only-using-javascript Also, please give credit to the user who posted the PHP code that you used, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604829/check-for-domain-extension-with-php-or-js

Comment: This isn't a code mill, what have you already tried and what doesn't work?

Comment: Do you expect us to rewrite it in javascript? Please try yourself first. If you fail, come back with a specific problem.

Comment: Did you try to google this: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+get+domain+extention  , basically it is impossible unless you have a list for all TLD's.You can split preg_match etc etc but when have .co.uk you are already screwed.

Comment: BTW it is always nice to see someone developed the exact same code someone else made.Déjà vu : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10604887/1316372

Comment: I posted that too Henry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the current hostname and break it into an array:

```
var host = window.location.hostname.split('.');
```

Then check it:

```
if(host[host.length-1] === 'de'){
    alert('this is a german site');
}
```

The last item in the array you capture will be the extension.

An alternative if you don't need to deal with older browsers (IE8 or older) is to use the `lastIndexOf` function:

```
if((window.location.hostname.lastIndexOf('.')+1) === 'de'){
    alert('this is a german site');
}
```

No need to capture in a variable that way, if you only need to call it once.

Comment: @Wind64bit - don't thank me, thank the checkmark. ;)

Comment: @Wind64bit if this answer is really what you need, then mark it as a correct answer, it's the green check under the vote arrow. And if you like the answer, then vote it up :P

Comment: @HenryW - not needed for the requirements of the question. ask a specific question, get an answer specific to that question. no scope creep!

Comment: i agree but if he emigrates, he will go hate you :)

Comment: @HenryW - he won't hate me nearly as much as he would if i overengineered a crazy regex solution that he would have to maintain without any tangible benefit.

Comment: But that would be a hell of an answer

Comment: @HenryW - if he hadn't given the checkmark to someone that copied my answer (in a terribly inefficient way no less!) I might be inclined, but at this point not worth it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var domain = (location.host)
var arr=domain.split(".")
extension=arr[arr.length-1]

if(extension=="de")
{
alert("this is a german site");
}
```

Comment: If or switch statement on "uk" tld.

Comment: @Ko Cour And can i please ask you one more thing if i was looking for the domain e.x www.cnn.com for the "cnn" i would make that `extension=arr[arr.length-2]` ?

Comment: @KoCour - appreciate you copying my exact answer, albeit in the least efficient way possible. always good to have alternatives.

Comment: Im not copying anybody, I started writing my answer when there were no answers.`arr.length-2` is good unless you work on co.uk and others.