# How to find URL domain using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was working on how to find a URL's domain, and thanks to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274884/rewrite-command-from-php-to-javascript), I came to this answer:

```
var domain = (location.host)
        var arr=domain.split(".")
        extension=arr[arr.length-1]

        if(extension=="cnn")
            alert("true");
```

However, I have 2 problems:

- It works fine untill you come across to a site with extension `co.uk`.
- Is there a way to count `.` from the start and not from the end?

For example, for the website `www.cnn.com`, it'd start counting from the `www`, and not from the `com`.

Comment: so what do you want ?

Comment: do you want the domain name and its extension or just the domain name ?

Comment: just the domain name for start

Comment: so in `stackoverflow.com`, you need `stackoverflow`?

Comment: Yes, but remember, there might be stackoverflow.co.uk

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253136/how-to-get-domain-name-only-using-javascript

Comment: What should be return value when CSS.programmers.stackoverflow.com and what for CSS.programmers.stackoverflow.co.in ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this function:

```
function GetDomainName() {
    if (location.host.split('.')[0] == 'www') {
        return location.host.split('.')[1];
    } else {
        return location.host.split('.')[0];
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var domainName=GetDomainName();
```

But remember, this will not work in subdomains like

```
programmers.stackexchange.com
```

Demo: <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/j7VP6/</kbd>

Comment: @Downvoter, dare to elaborate ? Or just taking revenge?

Comment: I am not looking for `www` but for `stackoverflow` only

Comment: Yes, I know that. It doesn't give `www` only `stackoverflow`

Comment: Did you even check it out ? @Wind64bit

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's the edit to make you understand how it works.

Say, your website is "www.cnn.co.uk". If you understand array, this line would return you the array of 4 elements delimited by '.'

```
var arr=domain.split(".")
```

i.e. [www, cnn, co, uk];

Now it's really upto you what element you want out of this array. If you know the element name, and you want to retrieve cnn, you can do

```
`extension = arr[1];`
```

You can also iterate over an array to get each element.

---

`extension = arr[0];`

it will return you www.

Comment: OP is asking for domain name

Comment: ? Thank you hello world

Comment: Thats what mate. OP is asking for domain name and not `www`.

Comment: when i ran it to cnn.co.uk it doesn't work, despite the fact that it works with cnn.com

Comment: @Wind64bit, mine works in that case. So please check out my answer